# Why i am getting the total count as ZERO even after importing 240 documents succesfully?

Tags: database, mongodb, sqlite, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Actually i was learning MongoDB and in that I got stuck in order to import a JSON file(which is located at Desktop of my laptop)

My JSON file is array of 240 element each of similar type as shown below (I have added two such documents in the array and similarly other 238 documents are of same form are present in the same array) :-

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "url": "http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/1/under-the-dome",
    "name": "Under the Dome",
    "type": "Scripted",
    "language": "English",
    "genres": [
      "Drama",
      "Science-Fiction",
      "Thriller"
    ],
    "status": "Ended",
    "runtime": 60,
    "premiered": "2013-06-24",
    "officialSite": "http://www.cbs.com/shows/under-the-dome/",
    "schedule": {
      "time": "22:00",
      "days": [
        "Thursday"
      ]
    },
    "rating": {
      "average": 6.5
    },
    "weight": 91,
    "network": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "CBS",
      "country": {
        "name": "United States",
        "code": "US",
        "timezone": "America/New_York"
      }
    },
    "webChannel": null,
    "externals": {
      "tvrage": 25988,
      "thetvdb": 264492,
      "imdb": "tt1553656"
    },
    "image": {
      "medium": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/0/1.jpg",
      "original": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/0/1.jpg"
    },
    "summary": "<p><b>Under the Dome</b> is the story of a small town that is suddenly and inexplicably sealed off from the rest of the world by an enormous transparent dome. The town's inhabitants must deal with surviving the post-apocalyptic conditions while searching for answers about the dome, where it came from and if and when it will go away.</p>",
    "updated": 1529612668,
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/1"
      },
      "previousepisode": {
        "href": "http://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/185054"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "url": "http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/2/person-of-interest",
    "name": "Person of Interest",
    "type": "Scripted",
    "language": "English",
    "genres": [
      "Drama",
      "Action",
      "Crime"
    ],
    "status": "Ended",
    "runtime": 60,
    "premiered": "2011-09-22",
    "officialSite": "http://www.cbs.com/shows/person_of_interest/",
    "schedule": {
      "time": "22:00",
      "days": [
        "Tuesday"
      ]
    },
    "rating": {
      "average": 9
    },
    "weight": 96,
    "network": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "CBS",
      "country": {
        "name": "United States",
        "code": "US",
        "timezone": "America/New_York"
      }
    },
    "webChannel": null,
    "externals": {
      "tvrage": 28376,
      "thetvdb": 248742,
      "imdb": "tt1839578"
    },
    "image": {
      "medium": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/163/407679.jpg",
      "original": "http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/163/407679.jpg"
    },
    "summary": "<p>You are being watched. The government has a secret system, a machine that spies on you every hour of every day. I know because I built it. I designed the Machine to detect acts of terror but it sees everything. Violent crimes involving ordinary people. People like you. Crimes the government considered \"irrelevant\". They wouldn't act so I decided I would. But I needed a partner. Someone with the skills to intervene. Hunted by the authorities, we work in secret. You'll never find us. But victim or perpetrator, if your number is up, we'll find you.</p>",
    "updated": 1535507028,
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/2"
      },
      "previousepisode": {
        "href": "http://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/659372"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Also I tried using this command:-

```
C:\Users\adity>mongoimport --jsonArray --db movie --collection movies --file C:\Users\adity\Desktop\tv-shows.json
```

And i think the data has been successfully imported as i got this

```
C:\Users\adity>mongoimport --jsonArray --db movie --collection movies --file C:\Users\adity\Desktop\tv-shows.json
2021-09-29T12:43:37.247+0530    connected to: mongodb://localhost/
2021-09-29T12:43:37.288+0530    240 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.
```

**But** when i run the following command it is showing me something non-expected outputs:-

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>net start mongoDB
The MongoDB Server (MongoDB) service is starting.
The MongoDB Server (MongoDB) service was started successfully.


C:\WINDOWS\system32>mongo
MongoDB shell version v5.0.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("590da209-aceb-4e56-960b-c950384ee3af") }
MongoDB server version: 5.0.3
================
Warning: the "mongo" shell has been superseded by "mongosh",
which delivers improved usability and compatibility.The "mongo" shell has been deprecated and will be removed in
an upcoming release.
We recommend you begin using "mongosh".
For installation instructions, see
https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/install/
================
---
The server generated these startup warnings when booting:
        2021-09-29T13:39:59.232+05:30: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
---
---
        Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
        metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

        The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
        and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
        improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

        To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
        To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()
---
WARNING: some history file lines were truncated at 4095 bytes.
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
movie   0.001GB
test    0.000GB
> use movie
switched to db movie
> db.movie.find().count()
0
> db.movie.find().pretty()
>
```

And I am using Windows OS.

Could someone help me why i am getting the value of count as **ZERO**??

Comment: Are you not able to move/copy the json file from your desktop to any other folder? See https://superuser.com/questions/1489874/how-to-get-the-real-path-of-desktop-in-windows-explorer

Comment: Please edit your question and put such information there instead of adding a comment. How does your JSON file look like? Please don't provide screenshots, use formatted text.

Comment: Your sample shows one JSON element. How are the elements separated? The `--jsonArray` option requires JSON file like `[{"id": ...}, {...}]`

Comment: Sorry new to asking question on this platform that's why there was lot of problem in understanding my question previously Now i have edited the question as much as i can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename is missing.

Use:

`mongoimport --jsonArray --db movie --collection movies --file C:\Users\adity\Desktop\yourfilename.json`

Instead of:

`mongoimport --jsonArray --db movie --collection movies --file C:\Users\adity\Desktop\`.

Or `cd Desktop` in your CMD and provide:

`mongoimport --jsonArray --db movie --collection movies --file yourfilename.json`

Comment: @Adityakumar You should select the DB first.
For Example : after ```show dbs``` type ```use movie``` and enter. This will take into the movie database and then type ```show collections``` It will give you the collection names. Then type ```db.yourcollectionname.find()```

Comment: @Adityakumar Your collection name is ```movies```. So please use ```db.movies.find()```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Studio 3T(https://studio3t.com/download/). The GUI supports import/export JSON/CSV etc..

Comment: What are you trying to do? Which OS?

Comment: I wanted to import a JSON file which is locate at my desktop screen (WINDOWS) using CMD(run as administrator) option.

Comment: Open the CMD in desktop and run the ```mongoimport --db=yourdbname --collection=yourcollectionname --file=yourfilename.json```

Comment: Are you using JSON array or Individual line of JSON objects(text)?
Can you share the format here?

Comment: @Adityakumar ```mongoimport --jsonArray --db movie --collection movies --file C:\Users\adity\Desktop``` In this line, you are not passing the filename.